# There (is/are) usually a green channel and a red channel at the customs

Tags: grammaticality, spoken-english

Just wondering which of the following sentences are correct and why?

> There *is* usually a green channel and a red channel at the customs.
>
> There *are* usually a green channel and a red channel at the customs.

I saw the first sentence in a book, but not sure why using *is* is correct.